# BreezeJS Integration with URF - Unit of Work & (extensible/generic) Repositories Framework

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework-6, odata, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

We are developing a SPA using (https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) framework as back end stuff.

We would like to introduce BreezeJS for data management at front end with Angularjs.

However, anyone please advice that how to introduce BreezeJS over above mentioned framework.

Any example would be nice to have as a reference.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some effort?

Comment: The above framework uses entityframework with generic repository and wrapped up by a service layer. where all the business logic might be placed. I would like to know, how to BreezeJS contextprovider can be pushed in to the generic repository indeed.